# Plus/Minus button with a counter but counter does not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 2 buttons and a TextView to update the counter based on how many times the plus or minus button was pressed.

But, the issue is that: (for example) When I press the "+" button to 4 and goes down to 3 after pressing "-" button. Then, when I try to press "+"(add) button again it jumps up to 5 instead of 4. (i.e. the counter continues adding 1 from when the last time "+" button was pressed.

This is the adapter class where the ImageButtons and TextView listeners are implemented

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        //inflate layout flavor_item.xml
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.flavor_item, container, false);

        //initialize UID views from flavor_item.xml
        ImageView imageIv = view.findViewById(R.id.imageIv);
        TextView flavorTv = view.findViewById(R.id.flavorTv);
        TextView quantityTv = view.findViewById(R.id.quantityTv);

        ImageButton minusbutton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.minusbutton);
        ImageButton plusbutton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.plusbutton);

        //getting data
        DashboardFlavorModel model = modelArrayList.get(position);
        String title = model.getTitle();
        int image = model.getImage();
        String qty = model.getQuantity();


        //setting data
        imageIv.setImageResource(image);
        flavorTv.setText(title);
        quantityTv.setText(qty);

        //plusbutton listener
        plusbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int count = Integer.parseInt(model.getQuantity());
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                count++;
                model.setQuantity(""+count);
                quantityTv.setText(""+count);
            }
        });

        //listener
        minusbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(model.getQuantity());
                if (i > 0) {
                    i--;
                    model.setQuantity(""+i);
                    quantityTv.setText(""+i);
                } else{
                    Snackbar.make(view,"Cannot have < 0 QTY",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            model.setQuantity("0");
                            quantityTv.setText(model.getQuantity());
                           }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                    }).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

(Note***) I tried checking the counter using getter and setter to check whether it worked and it did so I have no idea why when pressing "+" after "-" it wouldn't just +1 from the value after "-" button.

[image]

Comment: If you put `count` in onClick()?

Comment: yes I did and I couldn't set the counter global so I made it local. variables I & counter are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(model.getQuantity());
```

inside onClick for plusbutton onclicklistener

Comment: thank you! turns out I am just not smart with it and you were right